# How to loop through cells

Tags: vba, excel, loops

How can I update this VBA code so it can be a loop that checks all my columns,  ranging from G4 until G1000 and displays a msgbox for each and not only for G4?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim c1 As Range
    Set c1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G4")
    If IsDate(c1) Then
    If Now >= c1 + 60 Then
        MsgBox "The Date in Sheet 1 Cell B4 has been reached or passed."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `for...next` loop.  Use range("G" & x) where x is the variable in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using r.offset(0,-5) will refer to the column B

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Dim c1 As Range, r As Range
        Set c1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G4:G100")
        For Each r In c1
            If IsDate(r.Value) Then
                If Now >= r.Value + 60 Then
                    MsgBox "warning cell " & r.Address(0, 0) & " is expired: Value: " & r.offset(0,-5) 'r.offset(0,-5) will return the content on col
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim c1 As Range, r As Range
    Set c1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G4:G100")
    For Each r In c1
        If IsDate(r.Value) Then
            If Now >= r.Value + 60 Then
                MsgBox "warning cell " & r.Address(0, 0) & " is expired"
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Can the msg box contain the data that is written in B4 for example if the date of G4 is expired ??

Comment: @G.Rizk  You can modify the MsgBox

Comment: Yeah i know but i need it to give the value of another column which means the value written in B4 when G4 is expired. What should i write instead of r.value and shouldnt i define a new value?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you could use this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx

```
For Each c1 In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G4:G1000").Cells
    ' copy paste your code here
Next
```